# Sync contact from Mobile Application to Server side via REST API

Tags: mobile, architecture, contacts, whatsapp, restful-architecture

I just thinking, a mobile application just like WhatsApp, Viber, Telegram, etc, how can that great apps can efficiently sync those add/delete/modification done on the contact in our phone directly to their server side.

For the first time (whole contact sync), it should be a pretty much straight forward to directly send all those contact in phonebook to server to sync/upload process.

I would like to know, how can they manage the changes (incrementally) to sync the contact changes with the server side. If my assumption is correct, there will be a special process that can send only those updated contacts rather than sending the whole list every time.

Comment: Did you ever find anything interesting? I need to develop a REST API service that syncs contacts from a Mobile App and not sure where to begin.

Comment: @Pro5per : Based on my testing, it seems like the contact sync listener, only able to work if the user launch the app. Not really work on background. But it looks like good enough for most of the scenario.